# why puppeteer not allows pdf download when headless is set to false?

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer

in puppeteer, you can only download pdf in headless mode,

what might be the reason(technical challenges, or otherwise) that it could not be implemented in **head full** mode?

if you go to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions

it says `Generating a pdf is currently only supported in Chrome headless.` but I was curious why this might be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to the fact that in headfull mode there is a UI component involved when printing to PDF (the print dialog), and that's not solved yet. You can follow the open issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753118).